# PemReader.ReadObject() returns null when parsing private RSA key

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to create and sign a JWT using RS256. It should all work except that the PemReader returns null as it parses the private key.

I can see in the VSCode debugger that the private key string is part of the Non-public members and that it starts on position 0 and reads to the end but keyPair remains null.

I added the while != -1 to make sure that it read to the end, according to some other post.

```
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = null;

            using (var sr = new StringReader(myPrivateKey))
            {
                PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr);
                while(sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    keyPair = pr.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
                    if (keyPair != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }

            var rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
          
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                SecurityKey key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);

                return tokenHandler.WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "mee",
                audience: "meeeMee",
                claims: GetTokenClaims(),
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
            ));
            }
        }
```

Other things I have tried is this version below but the same thing happens.

```
private static RSAParameters GetRsaParameters(string rsaPrivateKey)
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rsaPrivateKey);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    // use Bouncy Castle to convert the private key to RSA parameters
                    var pemReader = new PemReader(sr);
                    keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
                        
                    return DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you include a test private key in the right format? We cannot tell why a read function returns null if we don't know the input...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the formatting of the private key. Once I read it from the private key file correctly using `string myPrivateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"filepath");` it now works.

Here is the full working code for creating and signing the JWT:

```
public static string GenerateToken()
        {
            string myPrivateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"path");
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = null;

            using (var sr = new StringReader(myPrivateKey))
            {
                PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr);
                keyPair = pr.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
            }
            var rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
          
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                SecurityKey key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);

                return tokenHandler.WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "mee",
                audience: "meeemee",
                claims: GetTokenClaims(),
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
            ));
            }
}
```

Comment: Does that replace the whole `using (var sr = new StringReader(myPrivateKey)) { ... }` part of the code?

Comment: @glenatron No, that is still needed to get the Key Pair. I basically just changed what the input to the `StringReader` is. I forgot to include the `myPrivateKey` string in the OP, but it is supposed to be there.

Comment: If you could edit the answer to include the working version of the function it might be a better reference for future users with the same problem.